# Does not contain definition or extension method

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I am getting next error when I try to build:

> Does not contain definition or extension method

I have a class like this:

```
[Serializable]    
public class JobFile
{
    private FileInfo mFileInfo;
    private string mJobNumber = string.Empty;
    private string mBaseJobNumber = string.Empty;
    private Guid mDocumentTytpeid = Guid.Empty;

    public string DocumentTypeDescription
    {
        get
        {
            string description;   
            DocumentType DocType;
            DocType = DocumentType.GetDocType(DocumentTypeCode);          
            if (DocType.Code == null)                    
                description = "Unknown";
            else                  
                description = DocType.Description;                   
            return description;
        }
    }

    public Guid DocumentTypeID
    {
        get
        {              
            DocumentType DocType;
            DocType = DocumentType.GetDocType(DocumentTypeCode);
            if (DocType.Code == null)
                mDocumentTytpeid = Guid.Empty;                  
            else
                mDocumentTytpeid = DocType.Id;
            return mDocumentTytpeid;
        }
    }
```

Now i am trying to get the value of Documenttypeid in my other class like so:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
{
    JobFile jf = null;
    jf = new JobFile(ref fi);
    f.DocumentTypeId = jf.DocumentTypeID; //<-- error is here
}
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: in `f.DocumentTypeId`, what's the type of `f` ?

Comment: Where is `f` declared in the loop? Shouldn't it be `fi`?

Comment: Please post full error text. And format your code yourself, it was unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, F is the definition fro another class called file.cs  I am wanting to set that Documenttypeid = whatever jf.documentypeid is.

Comment: We need to see that file.cs, with the definition of the type that F is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `f.DocumentTypeId`.

Assuming it's also a `JobFile`, it be `f.DocumentTypeID` (note the **ID** not  **Id**).
C# is case sensitive. Also, there is only a `get` property accessor, not a `set`.

---

If `f` is some other type, show us the code.

Comment: Thanks, f is actually another class, sorry I didn't put that part in there, i was trying to be brief.  I am setting the variables in the file.cs class (f) to do an insert over there.

Comment: If the type of `f` is `JobFile`, then my answer should solve your problem.

Comment: its not f is of type type file  ( Library.File.File f = new Library.File.File();)

Comment: The compiler is telling you that `Library.File.File` doesn't contain a definition for `DocumentTypeId`. Without knowing what you're expecting to happen, and without knowing what the definition of `Library.File.File` is we can't help further.

Comment: @ElPollo: I agree with George. The error is very clear; the property you're trying to get or set does not exist.

Comment: @ElPollo: If I'm not mistaken, shouldn't the error message tell you exactly what property is not being found?

Comment: I was going to say, working on this assumption, you haven't implemented a set method for DoucmentTypeID

Comment: Sorry to bother everyone with this.  I found the problem, and it was my own stupidity.  There is nothing wrong with the code itself the problem was my project had an old dll reference.  So doing a build on my project would not re-build the dll or Library i was referencing.

Lesson to learn: 
     **Always build in the proper order!!!**
Thanks for everyone's help in this matter!

Comment: the old dll didn't have a reference to the DocumentTypeID.

Comment: @ElPollo: If you can, add the library project to the solution, and reference the project, not the output DLL, then it'll build it first automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear about what's wrong. You're trying to use a property that doesn't exist, and seeing as how the error is occuring on this line:

```
f.DocumentTypeId = jf.DocumentTypeID;
```

It could only be one of two things:

1. `f` does not exist
2. `f.DocumentTypeId` does not exist.
3. `jf.DocumentTypeID` does not exist

Honestly, I would check to make sure that `f.DocumentTypeId` is not supposed to be `f.DocumentTypeID`. C# is picky about things like that, and a small mistake like that would cause the error that you're receiving.